# Object flipping on y and z axis when rotated on x axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm making a simple hoverboard controller, but when trying to rotate the character on the x axis further than 90 degrees(pointing straight up) it starts flipping on the y and z axis
Any help would be great, thanks.

```
float h_input = Input.GetAxis(HorizontalControlsAxis);
float v_input = Input.GetAxis(VerticalControlsAxis);

leanAmount = Mathf.Clamp(leanAmount + -h_input * leanSpeed * Time.deltaTime, -maxLean, maxLean);

leanAmount = Mathf.Lerp(leanAmount, 0, Mathf.Abs(leanAmount) / maxLean);

Quaternion targetLeanRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x + v_input * vRotSpeed, transform.eulerAngles.y + h_input * rotSpeed, leanAmount);
transform.rotation = targetLeanRotation;
```

I've also tried transform.rotate on the player, but the same problem still occurs.

Comment: The reason is you have 4 quadrants 1) 0-90 Sine, Cosine, tangent are positive 2) 90-180 Sine Positive 3) 180-270 Cosine Positive 4) 270-360 Tan Positive.  So when you go above 90 degrees the direction flips from positive and negative as well as the angle.  The simple solution is to test angle and then use different formula for targetLeanRotation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Quaternion targetLeanRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x + v_input * vRotSpeed, transform.eulerAngles.y + h_input * rotSpeed, leanAmount);
transform.rotation = targetLeanRotation;
```

rather use e.g.

```
transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(v_input * vRotSpeed, h_input * rotSpeed, leanAmount);
```

See [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html)

> When using the .eulerAngles property to set a rotation, it is
> important to understand that although you are providing X, Y, and Z
> rotation values to describe your rotation, those values are not stored
> in the rotation. Instead, the X, Y & Z values are converted to the
> Quaternion's internal format.
>
> When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the
> Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles.
> Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation
> using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite
> different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if
> you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.
>
> To avoid these kinds of problems, the recommended way to work with
> rotations is to avoid relying on consistent results when reading
> .eulerAngles particularly when attempting to gradually increment a
> rotation to produce animation. For better ways to achieve this, see
> the Quaternion * operator.